# Prove regular language and automata

Tags: regular-language, formal-languages

This is a grammar and I wan to check if this language is regular or not.

```
 L → ε | aLcLc | LL
```

For example the result of this grammar is:
`acc, accacc ..., aacccc, acaccc, accacc, aaacccccc, ...`

I know that is not a regular language but how to prove it? Is building an automata the right way to prove it? What is the resulting automata. I don't see pattern to use it for build the automata.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: To check whether a grammar is regular or not, just check whether the given grammar is either of right Linear form i.e. ` V--> T* + T*V ` 
or Left linear form i.e. ` V--> T* + VT* `
If the given grammar is any one of the above form then the grammar is regular.
So if you are given with grammar and wants to know whether language generated by the given grammar is regular or not, just check the above.

Comment: @Jarvis thank you! But I read that it's true that regular grammar produces regular language but it's also true that also unregular grammar (CFG) can produces regular language. What do you think?

Comment: In that case language generated by the grammar will be finite. If you have any example in which we can generate infinite regular language with non-regular CFG please let me know

Comment: @Jarvis What about this? The grammar _S->aAB;  A->aAb|ε;  B->a|b;_ is non-regular but produces an infinite regual language _a(ab)*(a|b)_ (found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23448734/how-to-construct-a-cfg-based-on-a-given-regular-expression) )

Comment: sir, the variable A in this grammar will not be generating (ab)* but instead it will generate _a^nb^n_  which is not regular but CFL. We wont be able to generate _abab_ from that variable A.

Comment: To generate (ab)*, we should grammar like A-> abA | null . Now this grammar is regular and clearly following V->TV*

Comment: Ok, @Jarvis . Thank you for your time. Just to be sure, one last thing. The grammar _A → ε | aAbA | bAaA_ is NON regular and produces a INFINTE language, so I can say that this language is NON regular as well. All right?

Comment: Yes. The best way to check whether the language generated by a grammar is regular or not is to check whether the grammar is right linear or left linear or not. But using this we can only check whether it is regular or not. This wont tell us whether it is CFL or CSL. See in this example, _A -> aAbA | bAaA | null_ , we will always have equal number of a's and b's. This is CFL clearly.

Comment: @cieco1109 Non-regular grammars can generate infinite regular languages all day long. You are absolutely correct that you cannot deduce irregularity of the generated language from irregularity of a grammar for that language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, let me quickly demonstrate that you cannot deduce the language of a grammar is irregular based solely on the grammar's being irregular. To see this, consider the unrestricted grammar:

```
S -> SSaSS | aS | e
SaS -> aSa
aaS -> SSa
```

This is clearly not a regular grammar but you should be able to verify it generates the infinite regular language of all strings of a.

That said, how should we proceed? We will need to figure out what language your grammar generates, and then argue that particular language cannot be regular. We notice that the only rule that introduces terminal symbols always introduces twice as many c as it does a. Furthermore, it's not hard to see the language must be infinite. We can use the Myhill-Nerode theorem to show that these observations imply the language must be irregular.

Consider the prefix a^n of a hypothetical string in the language of this grammar. The shortest string which can be appended to the end of this prefix to give us a string generated by this grammar is c^(2n). No shorter string will work, and that string always works. Imagine now that we were looking at a correct deterministic finite automaton for the language of the grammar. Then, whatever state processing the prefix a^n left us in, we'd need the shortest path from there to an accepting state in the automaton to have length 2n. But a DFA must have finitely many states, and n is an arbitrary natural number. Our DFA cannot work for all possible n (it would need to have arbitrarily many states). This is a contradiction, so there can be no correct DFA for the language of the grammar. Since all regular languages have DFAs, that means the language of this grammar cannot be regular.